# CSS overriding element with display property

Tags: css, css-selectors

here is my html code:

```
<div id="main_image" class="anim_hidden"></div>
```

and my css code:

```
section#header #main_image {
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    right: -100px;
    width: 546px;
    height: 509px;
    background: url('../images/iphone.png') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
}

.anim_hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Somehow display property is not overridden. It is if I use:

```
.anim_hidden {
    display: none !important;
}
```

or

```
section#header #main_image.anim_hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Do I really need to select element in this way?
I have more of elements, which I need to override with class anim_hidden.

Comment: ensure your highest priority styling is placed at the end of your css style sheet. Also, can you reproduce this in a jsfiddle>

Comment: all are `display:none` so what is the need to overwrite

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: If you want to hide something contained in visible div, i think it's better to include a div with class amin_hidden: `<div id="main_image"><div class="anim_hidden"></div></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be applied.
>   Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are composed of
>   selectors of different sorts.

Also note regarding `!important`:

> When an `!important` rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
>   it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do
>   with specificity.  ***Using `!important` is bad practice because it
>   makes debugging hard since you break the natural cascading in your
>   stylesheets.***

The different components of your CSS selectors hold different weightings related to degrees of uniqueness, `id` is deemed more important than class- and in fact can (and typically should) be used in isolation, i.e.

`section#header #main_image`

May be redundant *vs*

`#main_image`

As there should only be a single element with the `id` `#main_image` in a document (this is less relevant in instances of varying pages utilising the same CSS).

As such, you may want to look at constructing your rules with this in mind. At present, the initial rule is deemed more important because not only does it have more selector aspects, it has ones of greater weighting (`id`)

Alternatively, you can look to use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector to escape the `anim_hidden` instance:

```
section#header #main_image {
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    right: -100px;
    width: 546px;
    height: 509px;
    background: url('../images/iphone.png') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
}
section#header #main_image:not(.anim_hidden) {
    display: block;
}    
.anim_hidden {
    display: none;
}
```